# PHP Carbon date difference with only working days

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm trying to get difference between two dates in human format but only with working days. Here is my actual code:

```
$start = '2018-09-13 09:30:00';
$end = '2018-10-16 16:30:00';

$from = Carbon::parse($start);
$to = Carbon::parse($end);

$weekDay = $from->diffInWeekdays($to);
$human = $to->diffForHumans($from, true, false, 6);

var_dump($weekDay); //24
var_dump($human); // 1 month 3 days 7 hours
```

`diffForHumans` is perfect for my needs but I can't find any way of filtering like `diffInDaysFiltered`

What I would like to achieve is to get this result: `24 days 7 hours` because we only have `24` working days

I tried a `preg_replace` first to replace 3 days by `$weekDay` result but if we have a month before it's incorrect and I have: `1 month 24 days 7 hours`

Is there any solution for my problem ?

Comment: What if you just diff the time portion of the dates separately and add it to the diffInWeekdays

Comment: @chiliNUT This was my first guess to build it manually but I have the same problem if I encounter `month`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the answer thanks to [imbrish](https://github.com/imbrish)

I need to use the cascade factor to define:

- How many hours is a day
- How many days is a week
- How many days is a month

Then with the `diffFiltered` I can only select weekday and working hours. You can also add a filter on public holiday thanks to `macro`

```
CarbonInterval::setCascadeFactors(array(
    'days' => array(10, 'hours'),
    'weeks' => array(5, 'days'),
    'months' => array(20, 'days'),
));

$resolution = CarbonInterval::hour();

$start = Carbon::parse('2017-07-13 11:00');
$end = Carbon::parse('2017-07-17 18:00');

$hours = $start->diffFiltered($resolution, function ($date) {
    return $date->isWeekday() && $date->hour >= 8 && $date->hour < 18;
}, $end);

$interval = CarbonInterval::hours($hours)->cascade();

echo $interval->forHumans(); // 2 days 7 hours
```

Here is the [macro](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-macro) part:

```
Carbon::macro('isHoliday', function ($self = null) {
    // compatibility chunk
    if (!isset($self) && isset($this)) {
        $self = $this;
    }
    // Put your array of holidays here
    return in_array($self->format('d/m'), [
        '25/12', // Christmas
        '01/01', // New Year
    ]);
});
```

Then simply add `&& !$date->isHoliday()` inside the `diffFiltered`

Comment: can you elaborate on how to filter public holidays with macro?

Comment: @chiliNUT I've added the macro part

Comment: that is really cool. I didn't know about macro or cascade before today

Answer (score 2):

The above-mentioned answers are good correct. But there are some other ways also with carbon.

```
$startDate = Carbon::create(2017, 4, 4);
$endDate = Carbon::create(2017, 4, 18);
$no_of_days = $startDate->diffInDaysFiltered(function(Carbon $date) {
            return !$date->isSunday();
        }, $endDate);
```

Some useful functions of Carbon

```
  $dt->isMonday();
  $dt->isTuesday();
  $dt->isWednesday();
 $dt->isThursday();
 $dt->isFriday();
 $dt->isSaturday();
 $dt->isSunday();
 $dt->isDayOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY); // is a saturday
```

For more information go to https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The solution works, but i had some problem with more complex time calculation, so i figured out another solution with while cycle

```
    Carbon::macro('isHoliday', function ($self = null) {
            // compatibility chunk
            if (!isset($self) && isset($this)) {
                $self = $this;
            }
            // Put your array of holidays here
            return in_array($self->format('d/m'), [
                '23/12', 
                '24/12', 
                '25/12', 
                '26/12', 
                '27/12', 
                '28/12', 
                '29/12', 
                '30/12', 
                '31/12', 
                '01/01', 
                '02/01', 
                '03/01', 
                '04/01', 
                '05/01', 
                '06/01', 
                '07/01', 
            ]);
        });


        $end = Carbon::now();

$hours = 160;
while($hours > 0) {
    if ($end->hour < 9 || $end->hour >= 18 || $end->hour == 13 || $end->isWeekend() || $end->isHoliday()) {
        $end->addHour();
    } else {
        $end->addHour();
        $hours--;
    }
}

        Debugbar::addMessage($end);
```